# Alinhar tag span com html para adicionar borda

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, webdesign

Preciso realizar um alinhamento de uma imagem com uma tag span e colocar uma borda nessa tag span. Consegui alinhar, porém só deu certo colocando um margin-bottom de 1px. Funcionou, mas não gostei da solução. Alguém sabe outra técnica pra fazer esse alinhamento?

```
.rotten-tomatoes-rating {
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.rotten-tomatoes-rating img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  background-color: #ff0740;
}

.imdb-details span, .rotten-tomatoes-rating span {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0740;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="row col-md-6">
    <div class="rotten-tomatoes-rating">
      <img src="../../assets/2.Logos/logo-rotten-tomatoes.svg">
      <span >{{rottenTomatoesRating}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Resultado esperado do alinhamento]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa usar `margin-bottom: 1px`. O CSS tem todas as propriedades adequadas para alinhamento de elementos. Usar margin para corrigir altura, ao meu ver, é maquiar o problema.

Coloque a classe `.d-flex` na div onde estão a logo e o span para converter em flexbox (**teste sem o `d-flex` já que no seu print os dois elementos já estão juntos**. Não consegui reproduzir aqui exatamente como no seu print, por isso adicionei a classe `d-flex`) e defina a altura do span na mesma altura da logo, ou seja, `height: 38px;`. Desta forma os dois elementos terão a mesma altura.

Como o Bootstrap aplica por padrão `box-sizing: border-box` em todos os elementos, as bordas do span não serão somadas na largura e na altura do elemento. Com isso a logo não ficará mais alta que o span. Veja:

```css
body{
   background: black!important;
}

.rotten-tomatoes-rating {
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.rotten-tomatoes-rating img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #ff0740;
}

.imdb-details span, .rotten-tomatoes-rating span {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0740;
  height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
   <div class="row col-md-6">
      <div class="rotten-tomatoes-rating d-flex">
         <img src="https://icon2.cleanpng.com/20180619/fkv/kisspng-plum-tomato-bush-tomato-rotten-tomatoes-film-5b2942a0b53671.1232091215294306887423.jpg">
         <span>100%</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!